# Download Folder from Server with ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, ios, asihttprequest

Is it possible to download an entire folder from a server using ASIHTTPRequest? If not, can I compress the folder and download it instead. From what I have read, ASIHTTPRequest will uncompress compressed files. I have tried, but can't seem to get it working. I am not sure if I'm setting the paths correctly.

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:urlOfFolder;
[request setDownloadDestinationPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, @"download_folder"]];
```

Comment: It's still an HTTP request. Does your browser download the folder when you request the url? I guess it won't ...

Comment: It doesn't download it, but it shows me the listing of files contained in it.

Comment: @Kevin_TA have you solved your this issue? if yes , please provide me the solution for the same because i am also suffering from the same issue. thanks